# Complex function integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I have the function $f : D_f \subset\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ defined by
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2+2)}, z \subset D_f$$
where $D_f$ is the domain of $f$.

How do I calculate

$$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dx
$$
where $\gamma$ is circunference with center $-1$, radius $1$ and positive orientation?

Comment: Find the poles of $f$ that are "inside" $\gamma$ and use the Residue Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is holomorphic except at $z = 1$ and $z = \pm i\sqrt 2$. None of these points lie inside $\gamma$. Cauchy's integral theorem shows that the integral is $0$.

Comment: What if center is 0 and radius 2?

Comment: @ruvs In that case, the residue theorem is the easiest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Integral is 0 as there are no poles "inside" $\gamma$